# Passing variables into embedded Google Map using url

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Firstly, I'm new to javascript and google maps API. I've managed to get an embedded google map on a page, with a draggable marker that displays the updated lat and long. What I'm struggling with, is getting the initial marker location set using a variable included in the URL, for example:

http://example.com?q=12.989802,-80.2487

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>

<style> html, body, #map_canvas {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%
}
</style>

<body>Lat:
    <input id="lat" name="lat" val="40.713956" />Long:
    <input id="long" name="long" val="74.006653" />
    <br />
    <br />
    <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 100%; height: 90%;"></div>
</body>

<script>


    var map;
    function initialize() {
    
    var urlParams = /\?q=([^,]+),([^,]+)/.exec(window.location.search), 
            var myLatlng;

    if (urlParams) {
        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(urlParams[1]), parseFloat(urlParams[2]));
    } else {
        return;
    }
    
        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 8,
            center: myLatlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            draggable: true,
            position: myLatlng,
            map: map,
            title: "Your location"
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function (event) {


            document.getElementById("lat").value = event.latLng.lat();
            document.getElementById("long").value = event.latLng.lng();
        });
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize());

</script>
```

Comment: I get a syntax error in the javascript console with the posted code: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token var`, please provide a [mcve] that exhibits the issue.

Comment: This is incorrect: `google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize());` (should be `google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);`)

Comment: Your code works for me if I fix the errors above.